# simplexml object selector not accepting variables?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to load an xml node `<item id="n">`, where `id` is specified in `$id`.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("news.rss");
foreach($xml->channel->item[$id]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

will return `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object`.

However, changing `$id` on line 2 to a number, like `1`, will make it work fine. What's going on here? `$id` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `SimpleXMLElement` elements by attribute like that. The number in the square brackets refers to the element index (zero based).

If you want to find an element by attribute, use XPath

```
foreach ($xml->channel->xpath("item[@id='$id']") as $item) {
    foreach($item->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a, '="', $b, '"', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Demo here - http://ideone.com/Y6NGy2